# Incorect utf-8 encoding in wildfly 18

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, wildfly

I just can’t understand why setting up utf-8 encoding on the wildfly server, I get incorrect symbols in the MVC spring controller.
I send utf-8, receive utf-8 if view on CharsetDetector, but symbols incorect!
Help please!
Wildfly settings:

```
<server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" url-charset="UTF-8" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" url-charset="UTF-8" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </host>
            <host name="admin.study-lang.ru" alias="admin.study-lang.ru,www.admin.study-lang.ru" default-web-module="learningEnglishWords.war"/>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default" default-encoding="UTF-8" use-listener-encoding="true">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
```

Client js jquery:

```
var obj = {word: word, translation: translation, sentencesStr: sentences.toString(), mnemonic: mnemonic,
                transcription: transcription};

            var wordsJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "HTML",
                response:'text',
                data: "wordsJSON=" + wordsJSON,
                url: "saveWord.htm",
                success: function(data) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);

                    if(json.result == 'true') {

                        updateDataTable();
                        alert('Слово обновилось!');
                    } else if(json.errorMessage != undefined &&  json.errorMessage != '') {

                        alert(json.errorMessage);
                    } else {
                        alert('Ошибка при сохранении. Обратитесь к администратору!');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveWord.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> saveWord(ModelMap model,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String wordsJSON = (String) request.getParameter("wordsJSON");

    log.info("wordsJSON=" + wordsJSON);

    log.info(new String(wordsJSON.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));

    CharsetDetector detector = new CharsetDetector();
    detector.setText(wordsJSON.getBytes());
    log.info("detect=" + detector.detect().getName());
    log.info("detectq=" + detector.detect().getString());
```

Logs:

```
wordsJSON={"word":"blue","translation":"￑ﾄ￑ﾋ￐ﾲ","sentencesStr":"","mnemonic":"￑ﾄ￑ﾋ￐ﾲ","transcription":"ad"}
{"word":"blue","translation":"??????","sentencesStr":"","mnemonic":"??????","transcription":"ad"}
detect=UTF-8
```

my encoding filters:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: The log "wordsJSON={.." let's me assume that the content already was arriving as UTF-8 (pairs of non-displayable characters). But somehow corrupt. Assure that your client produces correct UTF-8. In any case, the statement "new String(wordsJSON.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"))" is completley weird. If you think this converts ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 you have misunderstood the string handling of java completely.

Comment: Heri, What is the correct UTF-8 encoding and not correct UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I replace symbols on unicode...

Comment: to ensure the correct encoding you have to look into the binary representation of the string, e.g. with UltraEdit or another tool which is able to show the binary content as hex dump. Non-Ascii characters must appear by a two or more byte representation.

Comment: Did you already try to specify the default charset on the JVM level, eg:
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ?